# WHERE clause seems to be messing up FIELD function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a simple query but just can't get it to work and can't find an answer online that's working correctly.  All I want to do is query a table with a where clause, then order those results based on some value.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation_form_results
    WHERE campaign_id = $campaignId
    ORDER BY FIELD(status, '$sortValue')
```

Here is what the data looks like (id is an int, campaign_id is an int, and status is an enum where the values default to undecided, but include good_fit, bad_fit, added):

```
id | campaign_id | status
----------------------------
 1 |          80 | good_fit
 2 |          80 | good_fit
 3 |          81 | bad_fit
 4 |          85 | added
 5 |          80 | added
 6 |          80 | bad_fit
 7 |          85 | undecided
```

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?  It currently works if I remove either the where clause or the Field function.  Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry I'm not using prepared statements for demo purposes.  $sortValue is coming from an ajax call, it's a dropdown value as a string that is either 'good_fit', 'bad_fit', 'added', 'undecided'

Comment: @thesofaking  Remember it's very easy for a "user" to mess up your ajax-call.  The only defense against SQL injection is the prepared statement.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific about what the problem is? You've shown what the data looks like, but what do *results* look like and for what parameter values, and what do you expect them to look like instead? Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know MySQL understood "$campaignid" as a variable, in the examples I see "@" being used, as in "@campaignid".
Anyway, in stead of FIELD (which needs a list of arguments, not an argument containing a list) I'd use LOCATE, with sortValue containing "good_fit,bad_fit,added,undecided":

```
SELECT * FROM reservation_form_results
    WHERE campaign_id = $campaignId
    ORDER BY locate(status, '$sortValue')
```

"undecided" will have the highest location, preceded by added, etc.

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ffb4e9f66856378125c9b76dd6d0c36)

[PHP MySQL prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Again, use a prepared statement, and have a variable $sortValue without quotes, just comma separated values.  A piece of cake for PHP.  See the link I added to my answer.